# Using EOF and getchar() to count the number of characters

Tags: c

I am trying to write a program for counting the number of characters in C. Below is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(void){

    
    // long nc;

    // for(nc = 0; getchar() != EOF; nc++);

    // printf("%ld\n", nc);

    long nc;

    nc = 0;
    while(getchar() != EOF){

        ++nc;
    }

    printf("%ld\n", nc);

    return 0;
}
```

When I execute the above program using the input :-

```
123<Enter>
```

then I press the control + ^d on my Mac to represent EOF, I am getting the output as 4D instead of just 4. Can anyone please tell me why I am getting D in my output?

Comment: Please check your input. The way it is written, you should be getting  7, not 4. Are you sure you enter spaces between the digits?

Comment: Control+^d? What is that extra ^ for? It should be just `Ctrl-d`.

Comment: Must be something specific with the way the mac translates ctrl+d, Try `echo "1 2 3" | ./yourprog` (your answer should be `5`)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yeah it is Ctrl-d.  it is just a typo when I was asking the question

Comment: @DYZ I added spaces when I was asking the question. In the input, I just gave 123Enter without the spaces.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I am getting the answer as 6

Comment: Are you sure the output isn't `D4` (or similar, with the `D` before the number)? Because that could simply be how the terminal shows the eof to you. What happens if you print an extra newline before the number?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Don't forget the newline... 

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah I am getting the output as 4D. Sorry I didn't get the part "print an extra newline before the number?".

Comment: @SaiSankalp `printf("\n%ld\n", nc) ;`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude - oops (your answer should be `6` `:)`

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yeah after adding your statement, when I give the input as 123<Enter>, it is giving me just 4, not 4D. why is adding a newline a solution here?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude even if I remove all the '\n' characters in the printf() statement, then also I am getting only 4. Can you please explain why is '\n' making a difference in the output?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I am following the textbook "Programming in C" by Dennis Ritchie. In the book, they gave printf("%ld\n", nc); if I use this, I am getting 4D. If I remove the '\n', I am getting only 4.

Comment: My ***guess*** is that the terminal program itself prints `^D`. Then your programs output overwrites the `^`, making it *seem* like the output is `4D`. With the extra newline, take a look at the line *above* your output to see what the terminal writes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude okay cool got it. yeah when I see the line above my output, it is showing as '^D'. yeah you are right. it is due to the overwriting issue. thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>[Turning my comment into an answer]</sub>

The "problem" is that the terminal program itself writes the output `^D` as response to the <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>.

With the original output of your program (without the extra leading newline) the program writes its output `4` over the `^` written by the terminal. The (trailing) newline from the program then makes the terminal go to the next line where the shell takes over and writes it prompt.

This will make it *seem* like the output of your program is `4D`.

As a possible solution, you might want to check the settings of your terminal program to see if its own output could be disabled.